# Display alert message after inserting a row in table using on demand process in oracle apex

Tags: javascript, ajax, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a procedure which is usually taking long time to execute. When this is executing, it insert a process log into a table.

For Example:

1. inserting row 1: Loading Data to Update...

//after some code execution

2. inserting row 2: Creating table abc...

I need to display these process log steps in Oracle APEX page item one by one, so that user can see the current step of the procedure execution in frontend.

I created a button (name: START_PROC) and calling a dynamic action which is executing one Ajax process using JavaScript code and in that process I have added htp.p() which is returning the content to one TextArea item.

But the problem is this returns all the process step inserted into table at one go, not one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest braking down the code into different PL/SQL procedures, each altering the session state, with the display item listed in "Items to Return"..
otherwise the session state of an item might change in the server side, but the command telling the client side to change is waiting for the process to finish